# NLog - Use appSetting for EnableSsl in mail section does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, logging, nlog

I'm using nlog to trace errors by email - all the configuration is stored in `web.config`. I'm trying to use `appSetting` for key `enableSsl` in nlog mail section but it is not taken into account for this specific key (but it works fine for other keys like: smtpServer, from, to, ...)

The following package are installed:

```
NLog<br/>
NLog.Extended // required to use appSetting<br/>
Nlog.Targets.Syslog<br/>
Nlog.Web<br/>
```

Documentation:
[Mail-target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Mail-target)

[AppSetting-Layout-Renderer](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AppSetting-Layout-Renderer)

Environment is C# .NET

It crashes with: `enableSsl="${appsetting:Mail.Ssl.Enabled}"`
It works fine with: `enableSsl="False"`

web.config :

```
<appSettings>    
  <add key="Mail.Server" value="mail.myserver" />
  <add key="Mail.Server.Port" value="25" />
  <add key="Mail.Ssl.Enabled" value="False" />
  <add key="Mail.Credentials.User" value="" />
</appSettings>

... 

<nlog ..>
    <targets>
        <target name="mail" xsi:type="Mail" html="true" replaceNewlineWithBrTagInHtml="true" enableSsl="${appsetting:Mail.Ssl.Enabled}" smtpServer="${appsetting:Mail.Server}" from="${appsetting:Mail.From}" to="${appsetting:Mail.To.Error}" subject="Error on my app" layout="${message}..." />
      </target>
  </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
      <!--<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="syslog" />-->
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="mailBuffer" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

nlog-internal.log :

> Error when setting '${appsetting:Mail.Ssl.Enabled}' on attibute
>   'enableSsl' Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Error when
>   setting property 'EnableSsl' on Mail Target[mail] --->
>   System.FormatException: ${appsetting:Mail.Ssl.Enabled} is not a valid
>   value for Boolean. ---> System.FormatException: String was not
>   recognized as a valid Boolean.
>          at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
>          at System.ComponentModel.BooleanConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.ComponentModel.BooleanConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
>          at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.TryTypeConverterConversion(Type type, String value, Object& newValue)
>          at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory
>   configurationItemFactory)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object obj, String propertyName, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory
>   configurationItemFactory)
>          at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationParser.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object
>   targetObject, ILoggingConfigurationElement element, Boolean
>   ignoreType)

Comment: `System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean` shows you an answer of your question , you should convert it to boolean

Answer (score 1):

`enableSsl` isn't of type `Layout`, but of type `boolean`. (see [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Mail-target)).

This means it isn't layoutable and so you can't use layout renderers for this value.

You could (as exception) variables in the config, as those are inlined when reading the config. e.g.

```xml
<variable name="myvar" value="true" /> 
...
<target name="mail" xsi:type="Mail" enableSsl="${myvar}" ../>
```

If you need to change the config dynamically, you need some code.